# Partition table by day ( datepart)

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

I want to create a partition on existing table.
It's a logging table that has 100K rows
and there are no foreign key constraint.

This is what i plan on doing;

1. create new_table with partition
2. copy data from old_table to new_table
3. sp_rename old_table to old_table_temp
4. sp_rename new_table to old_table

Is this the right process?
should i do all of this in one transaction?

would appreciate your help.

Comment: Add the DDL for your current table to your question. There may be easier/better ways to partition the table.

Answer (score 0):

> This is what i plan on doing;
>
> 1. create new_table with partition
> 2. copy data from old_table to new_table
> 3. sp_rename old_table to old_table_temp
> 4. sp_rename new_table to old_table
>
> Is this the right process?

This is very general as far as implementation goes, but yea sounds right. You could also just add the partition to your existing table to skip steps 2 through 4 if you don't want a backup of the old table without partitioning.

> should i do all of this in one transaction?

Ideally yes, if you want it to be transactionally consistent should any unforeseen issues occur. Wrapping it in a transaction will lock the old table until the transaction is complete, by the way. But 100,000 rows is small, so shouldn't take long overall.

---

On that note, why do you even want to implement partitioning on such a tiny table?

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the replay. The table is a log table and will grow much more in the foreseen future. I need to partition this tiny table for a truncate partition policy. So every day is a partition, and i create a job that will truncate the next day partition daily.

Comment: @dexon Gotcha, keep in mind partitioning isn't a performance improving tool (for DQL queries at least) but rather a data management enhancement feature. Sounds like you plan to leverage it for data management (by truncating by partition), so it probably makes sense in your case